# Book on discrete mathematics for self study

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, discrete-mathematics, self-learning, generating-functions

I am searching for book on discrete mathematics which is suitable for self study. This mean I want it to have exercises with answers (It would be ideal if it had solutions). I have already read "Discrete Mathematics" of Kenneth Ross. I have also partially read "Concrete Mathematics" of Knuth but I didn't like the style much. I am searching for next book to read. I do not have any requirements on topics I just want it to cover few of them like combinatorics and counting, recurrences and probably generating functions.

Comment: You can try with David Gries & Fred Schneider, *A Logical Approach to Discrete Math* (1993).

Comment: [_Discrete Math with Applications_ by Epp](http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Susanna-Epp/dp/0495391328)  I don't believe it covers generating functions though.

Comment: Bona's book "A Walk Through Combinatorics: An Introduction to Enumeration and Graph Theory" has a good chapter on generating functions.  The exercises are split into two categories, one with full solutions and the other without. http://www.amazon.com/Walk-Through-Combinatorics-Introduction-Enumeration/dp/9814335231

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Title sounds like it connects more rigorous logic and discrete mathematics which is what I may like. Could you write few sentences about this book?

Comment: Ch.1 - Textual Substitution, Equality, and Assignment; Ch.2 - Boolean Expressions; Ch.3 to 9 - Logic; Ch.11 - A Theory of Sets; Ch.12 - Mathematical Induction; Ch.13 - A Theory of Sequences; Ch.15 - A Theory of Integers; Ch.16 - Combinatorial Analysis; Ch.17 - Recurrence Relations; Ch.19 - A Theory of Graphs; Ch.20 - Infinite Sets.

Comment: "A Course on Combinatorics" by J.H. van Lint and R.M. Wilson .

Comment: Bogart's ["Combinatorics through Guided Discovery"](https://math.dartmouth.edu/news-resources/electronic/kpbogart/) is a nice resource.

Answer (score 3):

Epp's text on Discrete Mathematics is a very nice read. Johnsonbaugh is good as well, but is more technical and more geared towards computer scientists.

Nicholas Loehr's text Bijective Combinatorics is a great read for the topics you listed, which fall in the realm of combinatorics. Loehr's text is rigorous and thorough, but it is also very well written and intuitive. I did my undergraduate work at Virginia Tech where he teaches, and he has a reputation for being both brilliant and a fantastic instructor. His book lives up to that reputation, in my opinion.

Make sure you avoid Alan Tucker's Applied Combinatorics textbook. It's a horribly written book, and the only redeeming quality are the exercises.

Answer (score 2):

"generatingfunctionology"
by Herbert S. Wilf
and
"A=B"
by Marko Petkovsek, Herbert Wilf and Doron Zeilberger.

These are available
as free downloads at
https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html
and
https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a Discrete Mathematics course right now, using [Applied combinatorics by Roberts and Tesman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420099825). It does have some good 'real life' examples and applications.

Comment: Table of contents looks very promising but it is very expensive book.

Comment: @Trismegistos, It's an expensive book indeed, but I'm sure there are ways to get it if you know the right sources.

Comment: What do you mean Ragnar, do you mean an electronic version?

Comment: Most likely the pdf of the book.

Comment: If you search for a title, sometimes you get interesting results.

Answer (score 1):

Here are very complete notes and problem sets from Jacob Lurie's (Harvard) combinatorics course (Harvard).

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/155.html